# flutter_reactive_value: Getting an Error with just Importing the Package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-state

I followed the instructions for installing flutter_reactive_value as described [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reactive_value/install).

`flutter pub add flutter_reactive_value`

And I added the import on my main.dart:

`import 'package:flutter_reactive_value/flutter_reactive_value.dart';`

That's as far as I get.

I am on dart 2.18.  I tried it with all versions of this package (1.0.0 - 1.0.3).  Also, I downloaded the example (the entire project folder) located [here](https://github.com/lukehutch/flutter_reactive_value/tree/main/example) and got the same error listed below.  I tried this both as a Flutter web (chrome) and a Flutter Windows app.

Flutter web (Chrome) Error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
main.dart:1
: Error: The getter 'mounted' isn't defined for the class 'Element'.
reactive_value_notifier.dart:30
- 'Element' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
framework.dart:1
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'mounted'.
      if (elementRef.target?.mounted ?? false) {
                             ^^^^^^^

Failed to compile application.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Flutter Windows Error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
../lib/src/reactive_value_notifier.dart(30,30): error G4127D1E8: The getter 'mounted' isn't defined for the class 'Element'. [C:\workspace\flutter_reactive_value\example\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'C:\workspace\flutter_reactive_value\example\build\windows\CMakeFiles\6f135da36535027a04cd8738f00853c4\flutter_windows.dll.rule;C:\workspace\flutter_reactive_value\example\build\windows\CMakeFiles\335e6badeb606c6fb4bbef90392b261d\flutter_assemble.rule;C:\workspace\flutter_reactive_value\example\windows\flutter\CMakeLists.txt' exited with code 1. [C:\workspace\flutter_reactive_value\example\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
Exception: Build process failed.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Any ideas?  I am really hoping to use the simple state management that flutter_reactive_value offers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because of [this line](https://github.com/lukehutch/flutter_reactive_value/blob/21061a94c197875312b882a9d598a462d2c57c64/lib/src/reactive_value_notifier.dart#L30) in [flutter_reactive_value package](https://github.com/lukehutch/flutter_reactive_value).

The getter `mounted`, as the error says, isn't defined for the class `Element`.

Why it is not defined? Because [this getter was added to the `BuildContext` and `Element` only in `flutter 3.7.0`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/111619/files)(more precisely, [in 3.4.0-27.0-pre](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/085a187e047dde96b3f180f92c25159742f85ecd/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L3310)), and you are using some version below. [Here are the release notes](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/release-notes/release-notes-3.7.0).

What can you do?

1. Upgrade flutter to version 3.7.0 or above
2. Use [flutter_reactive_value package](https://github.com/lukehutch/flutter_reactive_value) version `1.0.1` or below, because the getter `mounted` was added to this package in version `1.0.2`.
3. Do not use this package at all. It provides only syntaсtic sugar, and can be replaced by `ValueListenableBuilder`, which comes out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thank you!  However #2 doesn't work.  I tried changing my pubspec.yaml to use version 1.0.1 and 1.0.0, and I get the same error.

Comment: You have to specify the version without the caret symbol(^):
flutter_reactive_value package: 1.0.1

If you specify it with caret symbol(^1.0.1) it means that you want to get the latest version of the package between 1.0.1 and 2.0.0(exclusive). And in the end you're getting the 1.0.3(latest compatible at this moment), which is not what you want.

See more about caret syntax here: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#caret-syntax